# Maximum of two random variables independent from the minimum

Tags: probability

Suppose I have two exponential random variables, $S$ and $T$.  Let $A = \min(S,T)$, $B = \max(S,T)$.  Are $A$ and $B$ independent?  I don't think they are, because:

$P(A = a \;|\; B = b) \neq P(A = a)$.  For example, suppose we know $B = 3$.  Then we know that $A$ must be less than $3$, because it is the min of two r.v. whose max equals $3$.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are dependent but not because those probabilities are unequal.  They're actually equal since both are zero.  Better to state things in terms of distribution or density functions.

Comment: @dsaxton why are they both zero? i'm very confused about it :(

Comment: I believe both $P(A = a)$ and $P(B = b)$ are zero because $A, B$ are continuous R.V.  Thus, the probability they take on any specific value is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct.